# Output of Reading a file word by word is not proper

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to read through a text file line by line and then I am trying to read that line word by word. Once I found a particular word, skip the remaining word from that line and jump to next
line.

But some words are getting printed in combinations.

I tried this way:

```
void SymbolScanning::symScanning()
    {
        std::string s;
        std::ifstream myfile;
        myfile.open("SymbolRead.txt");
        if(myfile.is_open())
        {
           while(std::getline(myfile, s))
           {
              std::istringstream iss(s);
              std::string word;
              while(iss >> word)
              {
                  std::cout << word << std::endl;
                 // if desired word found, skip remainnig word and jump
                 // over next line.
              }
           }
       }
       else
          cout<<"File is not open";
    }
```

```
I/p : line (60 * SCALE, 70 * SCALE, 106 * SCALE, 70 * SCALE);       
O/P : `line` , `(60` , `*` , `SCALE,` , `70` , `*` , `SCALE,` , `106` , `*` , `SCALE,`, `70` , `*` , `SCALE);`
```

I am expecting :

```
`(60` --> `(` , `60`        
                  `SCALE,` --> `SCALE` , `,`        
                  `SCALE);` --> `SCALE`, `)`, `;`
```

SymbolRead.txt :

```
/* version: v1p1 */

library("aacbnsfp_90spwd_9t45g_rxy") {
  SCALE = 1.0 / 10.0;
symbol ("PQXN67_0P5_9IJT16R") {
circle (75 * SCALE, -40 * SCALE, 5 * SCALE);
line (20 * SCALE, -20 * SCALE, 80 * SCALE, -20 * SCALE);
line (20 * SCALE, 0 * SCALE, 80 * SCALE, 0 * SCALE);
line (240 * SCALE, -20 * SCALE, 200 * SCALE, -20 * SCALE);       
......
......
} /* end of symbol "PQXN67_0P5_9IJT16R" */
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly why you are "expecting" this? What does "if desired word found" mean? Also, the shown input to the program appears to be rather garbled. Can you [edit] your question and fix its formatting, and also explain exactly what "desired word" means, and show the few lines of the missing code?

Comment: `operator >>` breaks on whitespace.  There is no whitespace between `(` and the `60`.  And to Sam's point, what do you consider a "word"?  The `operator >>` doesn't know English, and doesn't know what "word" means -- it will operate as written, and that is breaking up the line on whitespace.

Comment: Once you establish what a "word" is, then in all likelihood, breaking up the line on whitespace is the first step, where the next step is for you to write the code that takes each item returned by `operator >>` and parse it correctly in accordance to your rules for what a "word" is.  That doesn't come for free, you have to provide that part of the processing.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have updated my `SymbolRead.txt` file.  I was applying logic like : If I found `/` and `*` then I will skip that line ( as it is comment ).  If I found word `Symbol` then I will serach for `"  "` and whatever inside in it I will store it as symbol name.  If I find word `line` then `(` ownward I will consider it as 1st argument, then I will try to search for `,` after that there will be a 2nd argument like that I will try to find `;` once I get that, I will understand argument for line is over and I will store argument somewhere else and will be ready to read another `line`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  It is a simple logic but now I am feeling that implementing it is very difficult.  If you find any better logic , or if you want to correct above logic, please help me.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understood what are you trying to say.  Once I get `(60` then again I need to break it into `(` and `60` as I am interested in `60` only .  I tried to explain my logic in above comment to read the file. Please read that, and correct it if possible.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  After breaking on whitespace by `operator >>` I will get `(60` or `SCALE);` . How to break it them again in `(` and `60`  and `SCALE`, `)`,`;`  ? Can you help me ?

Comment: You need to tokenize the line based on more than just spaces, there are a number of ways to do that e.g. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/tokenizer/doc/index.html or roll your own

Comment: @tushar -- Do you only care about the alphabetic and digit characters?  Are you going to use the non-alpha characters?  Or what is the high-level goal of your program?  Maybe there are much better ways to approach *that* problem than how you're going about it now.  In other words, this is approaching [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) territory.

Comment: From what I see, you are approaching this the wrong way.  To process input lines like how you describe, an actual parser that works off of a grammar is what you should be focusing on.  Using stringstream seems to be the wrong approach altogether.